# to remove specific rows in a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

i want ro remove specific lines from the following csv file :

```
"Title.XP PoseRank" 

1VDV-constatomGlu-final-NoGluWat. 

1VDV-constatomGlu-final-NoGluWat. 

P6470-Usha.1 

P6470-Usha.2 

P6470-Usha.3 

P6470-Usha.4 

P6470-Usha.5 

P6515-Usha.1 

P6515-Usha.2 

P6517.1 

P6517.2 

P6517.3 

P6517.4 

P6517.5 

P6553-Usha.1 

P6553-Usha.2 

P6553-Usha.3
```

i want to remove the lines that begin with `1VDV-constatomGlu-final-NoGluWat.`

Comment: Is it just me, or is that a *comma separated value* file without any commas or separation?

Comment: This particular task would probably be easier to accomplish with sed or awk. (Although it's not a hard thing to do in any language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right solution is to use csv parser(i didn't test this code):

```
writer = csv.writer(open('corrected.csv'))
for row in csv.reader('myfile.csv'):
    if not row[0].startswith('1VDV-constatomGlu-final-NoGluWat.'):
        writer.writerow(row)
writer.close()
```

You can use also regular expression or some string manipulations but there is the risk that after your transformations the file will be no longer in csv format